# Video Editing in blender 2.8 - FFmpeg renders nothing

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to edit a video sequence in 2.8, tried it in 2.79 aswell but same results. I'm importing a mp4 with audio attached to it and the only thing I'm trying to do is to cut it down and render.

When I render to FFmpeg the render just gives me a grey empty render. Doesn't even render a empty file anywhere. I can render single frames in any format just fine and I can render AVI JPEG without problems, but that gives no sound.

Is there something I'm missing? It's driving me insane..

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Rendering animation from 3d keyframes worked fine, the same as you rendering into avi jpg or raw worked fine but ffmpeg just left a blank render window and nothing happening, no errors nothing.

As input I use a png image sequence of size 4800x6299 [px] (this is important).

I decided to add an effect transform with 2 keyframes at the beginning and the end with position x set to 0 (so no movement, just to get some keyframes to see what happenes) then I tried rendering and got an error saying: output dimension is not divisible by 2.

So I deleted the transform effect, changed height from 6299 to 6300 (1px is not going to make much difference anyway), hit render (this time again only the pure image sequence) and it started rendering.

So not sure if this can help you or not but I'd try checking that your output size both width and height are divisible by 2. If that doesn't work try adding some effect or something with keyframes and check if you get an error message as I did and try to check if yo uget any errors at the bottom.

This is after official 2.80 release so I'm nto sure if it's still relevant with your or not so I'm leaving this here if it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I made an account just to let others know that Vico Lemp's answer in here worked for me, I had to make my resolution divisible by 2 and then I could begin rendering an mpeg-4.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the video codec to MPEG-4 and it worked just fine. I suppose the other codecs were incompatible with the file format.

[image: A screenshot from Blender showing the video codec set to MPEG-4]

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine here in 2.80 of 15 of February, I just added the mp4 clip, moved the cursor where I want to cut, pressed shift-k to cut, deleted the unwanted parts, set the output to fmpeg, then choose mp4, compression quality, then press ctrl-F12.

Gilles